# Manage special character in cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this function to retrieve cookie in javascript

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Usually it works fine but I tried this function with a cookie storing an email address.

Each time the function run, the cookie is deformed. See the result of the following code:

```
setInterval( test, 5000 );

function test(){
    var email = getCookie('email');
    console.log(email);
}
```

Result :

```
test@test.eu    //At start
test%2540test.eu    //After 5s
test%252540test.eu    //After 10s
test%25252540test.eu
test%2525252540test.eu
test%252525252540test.eu
```

Why speical char such as '@' are misinterpreted ?

Answer (score 0):

If your first `getCookie` returns the correct data then you should check the function which modifies the data between intervals.

There is your problem.

Comment: The first getCookie (after 5s) get me `test%2540test.eu`.